# Security for select parts of a layer on ArcGIS Online dashboards

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, operations-dashboard

Currently I have an internal operations dashboard that is updated monthly with a new map provided by the field service team. This internal dashboard represents the information of multiple clients. All client information is on the same layer in the map. This is so that I can have graphs and counts of all clients if I decide I don't want to select information by client.

I'd like to come up with a way to share this dashboard and the associated graphs (which auto-update depending on the map view) with my clients. However, I don't want any of the clients to be able to see each others information.

I tried embedding the dashboard in StoryMaps with URL parameters to filter it by client, so each client would have their own StoryMaps. The problem with that is that in order to let them view it, I have to give their account permission to access the whole layer. While they can't see it in StoryMaps, they could potentially log in to ArcGISOnline and view the whole layer, including the data of our other clients. None of this data is particularly sensitive and I highly doubt any of our clients ever plans to log in to ArcGISOnline and go looking, I just don't think it reflects very well if anyone finds out they can do this.

I could have one layer per client on the map and only give them permission to access that layer. However, the associated graphs and counts and such on the dashboard can't incorporate data from multiple layers as far as I can tell, so I would need to make a new dashboard for every client. Which I can *do*, it's just more work than I want to do every month, especially in comparison to how easy the URL parameters are to append to a dashboard that I already make monthly.

Is there any way to implement the security I want on StoryMaps, so clients can view their StoryMaps but not the shared layer/dashboard on ArcGISOnline? Or any way to have a dashboard count items from multiple layers at the same time (so for the internal dashboard it will give me counts from all layers, but will only give the counts for the layer the client has permission to view on their end)?